# Copy folders by reference not by value?

Tags: reference, operating-system, window

So I learned in programming, we can copy a reference by passing it to a variable. Can we do something similar for reference to files and folder in Windows, if so how? (It will be reallyyy nice if I can edit the same file but from 2 different locations on the same computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Command Prompt, you can use **mklink** to create soft or hard link, for directories:

`mklink /D <the link> <original/target dir>` to create a soft link/symbolic link (to [learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/symbolic-links))

Or

`mklink /J <the link> <original/target dir>` to create a hard link/junction (to [learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions))